# I invested in bitcoin mining. Is this legit?

Tags: blockchain

I invested 250.00 I was told by a miner I could make 3200.00 in profit . Once my profits were shown on blockchain, it read non spendable. I asked what it meant and he said I'd have to invest 500.00 more to qualify for the minimum withdraw. Is this legit?

Comment: Such schemes are almost always scams (where almost = 99.99999%). You should cut your losses now and move on, absolutely do not send any more money to this entity/person.

Answer (score 5):

> **Is this legit?**

No, it's a scam. You gave money to a thief, don't give them any more.

Communicating to the thief is a waste of time, they are a confidence trickster who exploited your weaknesses once to trick you into giving them money. Don't let them trick you again. You have nothing to gain by communicating with them.

You will never get anything back, there is no way to undo this and get your money back. You can and should report this to the police but the scammer probably lives in a far-away country and the police will not be able to do anything for a 250 loss (even if that's BTC not USD or INR).

See [Mining Scams](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/search?q=mining+scam+is%3Aq)

---

> **my profits were shown on blockchain**

I guess you mean in a wallet managed by *Blockchain Luxembourg S.A.R.L (LU)* - a European business who run www.blockchain.com, www.blockchain.info etc. They are certainly innocent in this (though you could argue, to the government of Luxembourg, in which I guess you have no representation, that this business has a duty of care to its customers or to victims of its customers).

If the thief created this wallet or you created it and gave the thief the password, it is almost certainly a useless watch-only wallet. The thief can move money into it to make it look like you earned profits but those are illusory and not real. Changing passwords does not make the wallet safe, it does not lock-out the thief - they retain control over any Bitcoins sent to that wallet in past present or future.  It would be prudent to not touch that wallet ever again.