# Broker locked bitcoin wallet

Tags: wallet, fraud

I have a problem.

IS this a massive scam?

I invested £3,000 all in all with digital-miners.com the trader kept telling me that I could w/d my money anytime with no problem. Today I was told by my trader that I was no longer going to be trading with them as ''there were too many investors'' and a blockchain broker or someone like that would ring me, when I kept asking my trader about transferring money, he just kept saying the other person would ring me and kept avoiding the question.

When the other person rang me they said I had the money/bitcoin in my account but would need to send 10% £3,700 in advance to get the £37,000 in my account and it was now in a locked wallet. I can still trade with the money as I tried, but he says I can't get the money or bitcoin without paying the fee to liquidate it. I told him I don't need him to liquidate it, he can just send the Bitcoin to my Exodus account, but he said he can't do that without the fee as it is now in a locked wallet.

Anyone can help with advice on this would be appreciated. It was not done consensually and I don't understand why a trader would just drop me like that with £37,000 in my account unless it is to try to scam me out of the £3,700 to try to get the £37,000 that will never appear.

UPDATE... The guy who rang me about liquidating my funds has now said Digital-miners.com would allow the money to be refunded back to my account if I took down the post I made on trust pilot.. he said they would ring me about it.. I am still waiting for the call.

Comment: There was no £37,000 you have been scammed. The scammer tricked you into using an account or wallet that showed fake amounts. It was a trick all along. There is no way to get that monet with or without a fee because you never owned that £37,000. Report to police but forget about recovering the money you already gave to criminals, move on.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Refunding of payments if scam](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/96430/refunding-of-payments-if-scam), or [I invested in Bitcoin mining](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/80292/13866) or [How to recover my lost money](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/96670/13866) or [How to unlock the private key](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/77742/13866) and many many others.

Comment: digital-miners.com looks fake. Registered only 6 months ago, phone number in London but address in Dublin Ireland. You're wasting you time waiting for them.

Comment: If they have a UK number then you could try reporting them to the UK authorities?